# New to programming, issue with structures and functions

Tags: c

Hey I'm new to programming (learning through cs50x in C) and when they mentioned structures I decided to try to fool around and just write a quick program that would swap some values in a structure using a function. I'm running until several error messages, the first of which is "incompatible pointer types passing 'struct numbers*' to parameter of type 'struct numbers*'. Another issue seems to come up in the function definition where the compiler says "incomplete definition of type 'struct number'" I was just hoping for some help cause I'm stumped.

Heres the code (I know its rough but I'm learning lol)

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct numbers;
void swap(struct numbers* s);

int main(void)
{
    struct numbers
    {
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
    };
    struct numbers x = {1, 5 , 9};
    swap(&x);
    printf("%i, %i, %i\n", x.a, x.b, x.c);
    return 0;
}

void swap(struct numbers* s)
{
    int temp = s -> a;
    int temp2 = s -> b;
    s -> a = s -> c;
    s -> b = temp;
    s -> c = temp2;
}
```

Comment: "struct numbers defined inside main" and "struct numbers outside any function" are considered different types. Move the definition outside `main`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. While the question is generally ok, it will be easier for everyone if the next time you post a question you specify which line raises each error. Don't forget to mark one of the answers that solve your problem (if there is any) as the solution.

Comment: As previously said, make the `struct` definition global.  Also, put extra space between lines that deal with different things (such as after your `#include`, C does not care about indentations.  You may want to use `%d` in `printf` as well, it is more common.

Answer (score 8):

You're expecting the code in `swap()` to be able to access the fields of `struct numbers`, but the full declaration of that type is *inside* `main()`, so it's not visible.

Break out the declaration, it must be visible to all who need it. Putting it first will also remove the need to pre-declare the structure.

The same with `swap()` itself, putting it before `main()` will remove the need to have a prototype for it in the same file.

It should be:

```
struct numbers
{
 .
 .
 .
}

static void swap(struct numbers *s)
{
 .
 .
 .
}

int main(void)
{
 .
 .
 .
}
```

Comment: It might also be worth using `typedef` so that multiple instances of the structure can be created: `typedef struct { int a; int b; int c; } NUMBERS;` allows you to simply write `static void swap(NUMBERS *s)` in much the same way as you would use `int*` or `float*`.

Comment: Sure, that's convenient, but I don't understand what you mean by "multiple instances". That has nothing to do with `typedef`, and is not a problem in the OP's code. Note the line in `main()` that starts with `struct numbers x =`, that's creating an instance and there can be any number of such.

Comment: @unwind Hmm, it seems that I mis-typed; I meant to say "It might also be worth using `typedef` **for convenience if** multiple instances of the structure will be created". (This wasn't meant to be a criticism of your answer or anything - I just didn't think that it was worth being posted separately.)

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the `struct numbers` *declaration* is global, but the *definition* is local in `main`, To use the members of a structure, the `swap` function must know what members the structure have, and as it can't see the definition it doesn't know that. Remove the declaration and put the definition in the global scope.

Answer (score 4):

Function `swap` can't see the definition of `struct numbers`. Put it globally outside `main`.

Extra Tip - Use `typedef` with structs, it gives you flexibility in declaration:

```
typedef struct typeNumbers
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
} numbers;
```

Note that typeNumbers is optional. Declare it like:

```
numbers x = {1, 2, 3};
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the structure was in main, I did some fixes also to the code and comment them.

```
#include <stdio.h>

//By defining the struct at the beginning you can avoid the forward declaration 
//and it make more sense to know what "numbers" is before continuing reading the code.
struct numbers {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

void swap(struct numbers* s)
{
    //Small change to use only one temp variable...
    int temp2 = s -> b;
    s -> b = s -> a;
    s -> a = s -> c;
    s -> c = temp2;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct numbers x = {1, 5 , 9};
    swap(&x);
    printf("%i, %i, %i\n", x.a, x.b, x.c);
    return 0;
}
```